# How to return a copy of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, return, training-data

```
 public void addStudent(String student) {
    String [] temp = new String[students.length * 2];
    for(int i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
    temp[i] = students[i];
        }
    students = temp;
    students[numberOfStudents] = student;
    numberOfStudents++;

 }
```

---

```
public String[] getStudents() {
    String[] copyStudents = new String[students.length];

    return copyStudents;

}
```

I'm trying to get the method getStudents to return a copy of the array that I made in the addStudent method. I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: copyStudents=students.clone();
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149733/clone-method-for-java-arrays

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1) [Arrays.copyOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29)

```
public String[] getStudents() {
   return Arrays.copyOf(students, students.length);;
}
```

2 [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

```
public String[] getStudents() {
   String[] copyStudents = new String[students.length];
   System.arraycopy(students, 0, copyStudents, 0, students.length); 
   return copyStudents;
}
```

3 [clone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29)

```
public String[] getStudents() {
   return students.clone();
}
```

Also see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12157504/784909) about performance of each approach. They are pretty the same

Answer (score 1):

```
System.arraycopy(students, 0, copyStudents, 0, students.length);
```

Comment: so then I would say return copyStudents; ?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
System.arraycopy(students, 0, copyStudents, 0, students.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Java's `System` class provides a utility method to this:

```
public String[] getStudents() {
    String[] copyStudents = new String[students.length];
    System.arraycopy(students, 0, copyStudents, 0, students.length );

    return copyStudents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.arraycopy(Object source, int startPosition, Object destination, int startPosition, int length);
```

More information in [docu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) and of course, have been asked trilion times here on SO, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-array-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Arrays.copyOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29) to create a copy of your array.

OR

You can also use [System.arraycopy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Arrays.copyOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29) .

Eg:

```
int[] arr=new int[]{1,4,5}; 
Arrays.copyOf(arr,arr.length); // here first argument is current array
                               // second argument is size of new array.
```