# How does `array = array` actually work?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to understand what `array = array` actually does.

Why does editing `data1` leads to `data2` being changed later on in the process?

```
String[][] data1 = new String[5][1];
String[][] data2 = new String[1][1];

data1[0][0] = "Test 1";
data2 = data1;

//Prints "Test 1"
System.out.println(data2[0][0]);

data1[0][0] = "NEW";

//Prints "NEW"
System.out.println(data2[0][0]);
```

Comment: `data2 = data1;`. Both `data2` and `data1` refer to the same array (`new String[5][1]`)

Comment: I haven't done Java in a long time but I think this only works because the data type for both are the same. If let's say `data2` wasn't a 2-dimensional array of strings then `data2 = data1` will error out.

Comment: This is easier to understand in the C language where an array is actually the address of the first element of the array. `data2 = data1` actually make both variables point to the same array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, the array name actually holds the starting address of the array (similar to c/c++). The array index is the offset form the starting address.

So, when you use `array2 = array1`, you are essentially telling the compiler:

`"Let array2 hold the same address as array1"`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So to solve to problem I should just manually copy the array right?

Comment: @X3Gamma read pritam's answer

Comment: Except that both are refences which aren't addresses.

Answer (score 1):

```
data2 = data1;
```

At 4<sup>th</sup> line, you order that `data1` will refer to where `data2` refer to from now on. So, both references refer to same object. Any modification by using one of the references will be seen by each other. That's what `=` operator actually does in Java. Technically, it is *reference copying* in this way.

Comment: Questions like this show that operator overloading is a *bad* idea. Glad Java doesn't have it.

Comment: @M.leRutte It depends. Just because one needs to be careful when overloading operators doesn't mean that operator overloading is a bad thing; it just means that one should do it with care and only where it makes sense.  That's my two cents at least.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the previous answers that it refers to the same location when you use the `=` operator, changes are reflected in both.

If you don't want that then you should use clone the arrays. You can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149733/clone-method-for-java-arrays) on how to do it.