# When change values of cloned array, changes the source array values

Tags: java, arrays, clone

Please see this below code, i have two 2D array, when i change values of the `goalState` array, the values of `startState` changes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    int[][] startState = new int[][]{{1, 2, 3}, {8, 0, 4}, {7, 6, 5}};
    int[][] goalState = new int[][]{};

    goalState = startState.clone();

    goalState[0][1] = 12;

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(startState));
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(goalState));
}
```

output:

```
[[1, 12, 3], [8, 0, 4], [7, 6, 5]]
[[1, 12, 3], [8, 0, 4], [7, 6, 5]]
```

Comment: you could find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149733/clone-method-for-java-arrays

Comment: i also used `clone`, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clone as below,

```
for (int i=0; i<startState.length; i++) {
    goalState[i] = startState[i].clone();
}
```

With java-8+,

```
int[][] goalState = Arrays.stream(startState)
                          .map(int[]::clone)
                          .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

Comment: Why this works:  clone() is essentially a shallow copy (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175620/in-java-what-is-a-shallow-copy), so you need to "go deeper" and clone each object separately if you don't want changes to both

Answer (score 1):

So, After analysing heap dump of your code , it seems on doing startState.clone(), then all the  references of 1 d array (like reference of {1,2,3}) are copied from startState to goalState

[image]

GoalState memory object:
    [image]
That's why any change you do in goalState will be reflected in startState and vice -versa.

So , in order to fix this all you need to do is:

```
    int[][] startState = new int[][]{{1, 2, 3}, {8, 0, 4}, {7, 6, 5}};
    int[][] goalState = new int[startState.length][startState[0].length];

    for(int i=0;i<startState.length;i++)
    {goalState[i]=startState[i].clone();}
```

Note, this will  only work in case of primitive type array ,as In primitive type 1d array only value of int is copied, and that's why we can use this feature in cloning of 2d array also