# Storing a sorted array in Java, not understanding .clone() Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, clone

I am trying to store a sorted array separate from the original array. I need to be able to access both arrays without altering the original in anyway. I have tried to understand how to to .clone but I can't seem to understand what I am doing wrong. I have my code below, I am passing an array from above into this method and want to sort and store it. Am I even close to being correct here?

```
public static double sortArray(int[] array) {
        //Sort the array
        Object tempObj = array.clone();
        Arrays.sort(tempObj);
        sortedArray[] = tempObj;
```

Comment: where are you trying to store this array?

Comment: are you trying to clone the exact values?

Comment: `int[] sortedArray = array.clone(); Arrays.sort(sortedArray);`

Comment: you declare on return type `double`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149733/clone-method-for-java-arrays

This answer explains the use of the clone() method

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the new sorted array, using java 8 streams:

```
int[] newArr = Arrays.stream(array).sorted().toArray(int[]::new);
```

Then change your method return type to int[]:

```
public static int[] sortArray(int[] array) 
{
    int[] newArr = Arrays.stream(array).sorted().toArray(int[]::new); 
    return newArr; 
}
```

Comment: you could use `return` immediately without creating `int[] newArr` reference :)

Comment: yes, but he said he wanted to keep track of both array's so i just did that for clarity